# Under what login/boot conditions can Chrome Remote Desktop access a computer? Does this differ by OS?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, remote-access, cross-platform, chrome-remote-desktop

If I set up a host computer for permanent remote access via Chrome Remote Desktop, when is it accessible?

Specifically:

- Is it accessible when it has been locally logged into only by a non-administrator user?
- Is it accessible when a user (admin or non) is locally logged in who is not the user that installed Chrome Remote Desktop in the first place?
- Is it accessible when it has been locally logged into and then locked?
- Is it accessible when it has been powered on but not yet logged into?
- If not, when, after a restart, does a host computer become accessible? Is there a user-specific service which starts after a particular user logs in that enables Chrome Remote Desktop access? If so, can that service be set up such that it starts with the system (before login)?
- Is it still accessible when it has been on during a period of time in which its external IP has changed (assuming the host computer's DNS/DHCP have properly updated)?

For the above cases, the following can be assumed:

- Chrome Remote Desktop was installed in permanent-access mode on the host computer.
- Chrome is *not* open on the host computer.
- The host computer is always connected to a physical (Ethernet) internet connection.

I only have a Windows XP PC to play with right now, but I would like to know those details for other major OSes (Win7, Win8, OSX).

Comment: Have you resarched this at all?  How Chrome Remote Desktop works wouldn't be effected by the operating sytem.

Answer (score 6):

In windows 8.1 I am able to remotely reboot and then login again using Chrome Remote Desktop.  So, the remote computer needs to be on and connected to the network, but does not need to be logged in.

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Remote_Desktop) is remote desktop software that is configured through a Chrome extension inside of Chrome the browser. It installs a background service (named `Chrome Remote Desktop Service` on Windows) to transmit keyboard/mouse input from one computer and video from the other.

It uses a signed in Google account to maintain a list of shared computers. Chrome does not need to be running to connect but the computer must be up and connected to the Internet. I have not verified with a multiple user system but it presents my Windows login screen when I remote from work.

Google support has more information [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649523)

Answer (score 2):

But, what I've found with OS X Mavericks is the second you log out Chrome Remote Desktop disconnects.  You can connect again successfully, but you are met with a solid black screen and can't do anything.  If you connect with another solution, like LogMeIn for example, you will find that that black screen is in fact there too... I'm also guessing that means the black unusable screen would be staring at you from the monitor too.  Have to hard reboot the machine to fix it as far as I can tell.

Comment: I often login to my home Mac from my work Windows 7 machine. I have had the same experience (the black screen), as well as an OS X login screen that won't respond at all (to mouse clicks, keystrokes, nothing) on OS X Mountain Lion and now Mavericks. But I've also noticed that if I disconnect, wait an hour or two, and then reconnect, usually everything is copacetic, no rebooting necessary.